# Number of solutions for rat in a maze puzzle

Tags: c, recursion

Rat in Maze Puzzle - A Maze is given as N*N binary matrix of blocks where source block is the upper left most block i.e., maze[0][0] and destination block is lower rightmost block i.e., maze[N-1][N-1]. A rat starts from source and has to reach destination. The rat can move any directions: forward,down,Left,Right.In the maze matrix, 0 means the block is dead end and 1 means the block can be used in the path from source to destination.
[image]

Problem - Find all possible solutions and the number of solutions to get the rat out of the maze.
I was able to find a "single solution" for rat in a maze puzzle. But how do i determine different possible solutions and the number of solutions? Pasting the code below which will determine a single solution and prints the same. Please help me how do i determine different possible solution and the number of solutions as well.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define N 5 //Maze Size 5X5 matrix

//Function declarations
void maze(int m[N][N]);
int maze_soln(int soln[N][N], int m[N][N],int ,int,int path[N][N]);
int issafe(int m[N][N], int x, int y,int path[N][N]);

// This function checks for valid cell. If already visited in the past
// path[][] will take care of returning false.
int issafe(int m[N][N], int x, int y,int path[N][N])
{
    if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < N && y < N && m[x][y] == 1 && path[x][y] !=1)
        return true; // Valid cell.
    else
        return false;
}

// Maze solutions. Checks for proper cell. finds proper path 
// By going LEFT,RIGHT,UP or DOWN
int maze_soln(int soln[N][N], int m[N][N],int x,int y,int path[N][N])
{
    //All the cells have been visited
    if (x == N - 1 && y == N - 1)
    {
        soln[x][y] = 1; //mark the cell as possible path
        return true;
    }

    // Find out different paths
    if (issafe(m, x, y,path) == true)
    {
        soln[x][y] = 1; // mark the cell as possible solution
        path[x][y] = 1; //mark the path as visited

        // Go RIGHT and see if there's a path
        if (maze_soln(soln, m, x, y + 1,path))
            return true;

        //LEFT
        if (y> 0 && maze_soln(soln, m, x, y-1,path))
            return true;

        //DOWN
        if (maze_soln(soln, m, x + 1, y,path))
            return true;

        //UP
        if (x>0 && maze_soln(soln, m, x - 1, y,path))
            return true;

        soln[x][y] = 0;
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

// Prints the solution matrix if proper path is found
void maze(int m[N][N])
{
    int i, j;
    int soln[N][N] = { 0 };
    int path[N][N] = { 0 };
    if (maze_soln(soln, m, 0, 0,path) == true)
    {
        printf("\n Solution\n"); //Print solution matrix
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                printf("\t%d", soln[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return;
}

// Main function
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    //Maze matrix
    int m[N][N] = { { 1,1,1,0,0 },
                    { 1,1,0,1,0 },
                    { 0,1,0,1,1 },
                    { 1,1,1,1,1 },
                    { 1,0,0,1,1 } };

    //Print the Maze
    printf("MAZE\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            printf("\t%d", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //Call maze function to find out the path
    // and print the solution matrix
    maze(m);
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: I have added more details as to what i need. Please remove the hold

Comment: What is the puzzle? Describe in words, it will help to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Puzzle definition Added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return early when you have found the first solution. If you want to see further solutions, you must keep going and explore all paths. Instead of a truth value your core function now returns the number of solutions.

You must store the solutions when you find them, of course, so that you can print them later. This can be quite memory-heavy, because in a sparse maze there may be many possible solutions. You also don't know up front how many solutions there are.

A simple alternative is therefore to print the current solution once you have found it.

Unrelated to your question, but you don't really need three separate arrays. You can use the original array of walls and space when you add another possible value, visited space. This value acts as the breadcrumbs that tell you where you have been already. A valid next step can only be to an unvisited space.

Putting this into practice, you get, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 5

int issafe(int m[N][N], int x, int y)
{
    if (x < 0 || x >= N) return 0;
    if (y < 0 || y >= N) return 0;

    return (m[x][y] == 1);
}

void print(int m[N][N])
{
    static const char *glyph = "#.*";
    static int nsol = 0;
    int i, j;

    printf("Solution %d\n\n", ++nsol);

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            putchar(glyph[m[i][j]]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int maze(int m[N][N], int x, int y)
{
    int nsol = 0;

    if (issafe(m, x, y)) {
        m[x][y] = 2;

        if (x == N - 1 && y == N - 1) {
            print(m);
            nsol = 1;
        } else {
            nsol += maze(m, x, y + 1);
            nsol += maze(m, x, y - 1);
            nsol += maze(m, x + 1, y);
            nsol += maze(m, x - 1, y);
        }

        m[x][y] = 1;
    }

    return nsol;
}

int main()
{
    int m[N][N] = { 
        { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 } 
    };
    int nsol;

    nsol = maze(m, 0, 0);
    printf("%d solutions.\n", nsol);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.